# Getting not found SourceFolder in TFS 2015 build

Tags: tfs

We're experiencing problems with a build, since had been working fine up until last week Thursday. Now we get this error whenever it runs:

> Not found SourceFolder:
>   C:\agent_work\34\s\PharmacyWarehouse\PharmacyWarehouse\bin\release\app.publish

This is in our test build environment. It fails on the Copy Files task. Both the source and destination folders are on the build server, so I think Copy Files would be fine. Here's our environment for test:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your description and error message. This may related to cache for build agent/server.

When you add a **Visual Studio Build / MSBuild task** to build the project, make sure you have checked the **Clean** option or set `Clean=True`. Thus it will delete all got source and generated build output which generated from prior builds.

> **Clean Option :** Set to False if you want to make this an incremental build. This setting might reduce your build time,
>   especially if your codebase is large. This option has no practical
>   effect unless you also set Clean repository to False.
>
> Set to True if you want to rebuild all the code in the code projects.
>   This is equivalent to the MSBuild `/target:clean argument`.

[image]

Also check if there are enough drive space in your build agent/server.

Besides, you could also reinstall build agent or [upgrade your build agent version](https://github.com/microsoft/azure-pipelines-agent). This will force delete/recreate working folder. Which may do the trick.